# DAX measure with HTML

Tags: html, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

_Hi, I have the functionnal DAX/HTML following measure I Put in an HTML add visual in powerbi :

```
VAR _PriceInfo = 
    "<b>" & _CurrentPrice & "<br><font size = -2></b>" & 
        IF(
            [Price Variation] >= 0,
            "<font color = " &[Color Green] & ">" & "+ " & _Variation,
            "<font color = " &[Color Red] & ">" & _Variation
          )
```

But I would like to transform it to HTML5. I did the following try but it won't work for the IF part ? Thanks in advance for your help !

```
"<p style='font-weight: bold;'>" & _CurrentPrice & "<br><span style='font-size: small;'></span></p>" &
    IF(
        [Price Variation] >= 0, 
        "<span style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>+ " & _Variation & "</span>",
        "<span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>" & _Variation & "</span>"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE START**

```
Price Info Formatted = 
VAR _CurrentPrice = FORMAT([Current Price], "$###,###,##0.00")
VAR _Variation = FORMAT([Price Variation],"$###,###,##0.00") & " (" & FORMAT([Price Percentage Variation], "0.00%") & ")"
VAR _x =  "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" & _CurrentPrice & "</span><br/>"

RETURN
    IF(
            [Price Variation] >= 0, 
            _x & "<span style='color: green; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;'>+ " & _Variation & "</span>",
            _x & "<span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;'>" & _Variation & "</span>"
    )
```

**UPDATE END**

Try this:

```
measure = 
VAR x =  "<p style='font-weight: bold;'>" & _CurrentPrice & "<br><span style='font-size: small;'></span></p>" 

RETURN
        IF(
            [Price Variation] >= 0, 
            x & "<span style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>+ " & _Variation & "</span>",
            x & "<span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>" & _Variation & "</span>"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Davide. Still good for the VAR part. Still doesn't appear for the second one, but much clearer syntax... Any idea ?

Comment: The code looks fine on reading. What exactly is the issue you're seeing? Can you share a .pbix and what your expected result is?

Comment: yep. My concern is to display the result of the "Price Info Formatted" measure. Here is the link of my file : https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8TKb6Fb7Z69AzrA9?e=Dh6uMH

Comment: It looks like it is already working to me? Microsoft is red and others are green. Is that not how they're supposed to be?

Comment: yes it works but I wanted to tranform the html code in html 5 and then, my try won't work ? (code update)

Comment: I'll update now

Comment: Thanks a lot ! However this HTML5 code adds basically a line above and bottom the paragraph.  The code needs to become : "<p style='font-weight: bold;margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;'>" & _CurrentPrice & "<br><span style='font-size: small;'></span></p>"